# Errors appending text with `sed`

Tags: bash, sed, docker, for, podman

I have a `podman-compose` file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  kiwix-serve:
    image: docker.io/kiwix/kiwix-serve:3.3.0-1
    volumes:
      - kiwix_data:/data
      - /home/meijin3/zim/gutenberg_en_all_2022-10.zim:/data/gutenberg_en_all_2022-10.zim
      - /home/meijin3/zim/wikipedia_en_all_mini_2022-09.zim:/data/wikipedia_en_all_mini_2022-09.zim
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    command:
      /data/wikipedia_en_all_mini_2022-09.zim
      /data/gutenberg_en_all_2022-10.zim
```

I'm attempting to create a script that will search for all `.zim` files in `/home/meijin3/zim/`. It will replace any existing lines in my compose file that contain references to `.zim` files.

```
#!/bin/bash

yaml=example.yaml

sed -i '/.zim/d' $yaml

for i in "$(find /home/meijin3/zim/*.zim -printf '%f\n')"; do \
line1='home/emilio/zim/'"$i"':/data/'"$i"
sed -i -e "\,kiwix_data,a "'\ \ \ \ \ \ - '"$line1" "$yaml"; done

batcat $yaml
```

For some reason that I can't seem to understand I keep getting the following error:
`sed: couldn't open file ikipedia_en_all_mini_2022-09.zim:/data/gutenberg_en_all_2022-10.zim: No such file or directory`

If I have only one file in `/home/meijin3/zim/`, my script runs without any issues (other than the fact that I have yet to add the lines to the command section yet).

Am I not using the proper syntax for the `sed` command? Perhaps the issue lies somewhere else. If you're able to help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Sometimes it can be helpful posting a question here after being stumped for a while just to help think through the problem as I explain it. I ended up running `set -x` and taking a look at my output which was a complete mess. I ended up resolving my issue by outputting my `find` command to an array and iterating over that. I'll post the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue by assigning the output of my `find` command to an array, i.e.,

```
zim_files=($(find /home/meijin3/zim/*.zim  -printf '%f\n'))
```

I modified my `for` loop to iterate over this array:

```
for i in ${zim_files[@]}; do
  sed -i -e '\,kiwix_data,a \ \ \ \ \ \ - /home/meijin3/zim/'"$i"':/data/'"$i" "$yaml"
  sed -i -e "\,command:,a "'\ \ \ \ \ \ /data/'"$i" "$yaml"
done
```